# Moving image files in Github to folder

Tags: git, github

I am moving my website to Github Pages, but have made a mistake in not keeping the same folder names. Instead I just uploaded every file to the main repository.
My repository is here : https://github.com/akinhwan/akinhwan.github.io

I am aware of how to change the file directories of text files, by clicking the edit icon and adding a root name and "/". However image files do not appear to have this option.

How might I use github, git shell or github desktop to move my many image files to a subfolder /img so that my html will be able to find my image files?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this using command-line `git`,

- Type `git clone https://github.com/akinhwan/akinhwan.github.io` to download a local copy of the repository, then `cd akinhwan.github.io` to go into that directory.
- Make a directory called `img` by running `mkdir img`.

  - Create extra directories in this way as necessary if you need to reorganize any other types of file.
- Move the images into the new directory by running `git mv *.jpg *.png *.gif img/`

  - This can be done for individual files like `git mv file.png destination/`
- Once you are happy with what you have moved (use a graphical file manager if necessary to review the locations of moved files, and use `git status` to see what you have changed), run `git commit -m 'Move image files to /img'` or similar to make a new commit which moves your files to their correct locations.
- Push the commit to the repository on GitHub by running `git push` and entering your credentials.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up finding additional directions here. Which evaded my initial github help searches or google searches. I will paste here for future reference anyone who asks his question  here on stackoverflow.

https://help.github.com/articles/moving-a-file-to-a-new-location-using-the-command-line/